# sparql regex compare two string variables (one is composed by the other)

Tags: regex, contains, sparql

I am trying to compare two string variables to discover if one is contained in the other, specifically if one is composed of the other (so, I would like to avoid retrieving that "information" contains "format". I am interested only in results similar to "information_management" includes "information".

I have tried both FILTER CONTAINS() and FILTER regex() with the same results. How can I modify the query so it includes the fact that there needs to be a space either before or after the term?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?l1 ?l2
WHERE
{
?term1 skos:prefLabel ?l1.
?term2 skos:prefLabel ?l2.
FILTER(contains(?l1,?l2))
}
```

Comment: I revised my answer because I think I didn't answer your whole question in my original answer

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly you want to find pairs of terms where one term is contained in the other *but* is not equal to the other?

If so you can add a `!SAMETERM()` call into the the `FILTER` clause like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?l1 ?l2
WHERE
{
  ?term1 skos:prefLabel ?l1.
  ?term2 skos:prefLabel ?l2.
  FILTER(!SAMETERM(?l1, ?l2) && contains(?l1,?l2))
}
```

**Edit**

Re-reading the question I don't think I addressed the whole question, for the problem where you have the terms "format" and "information" and don't want them to be matched you can do something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?l1 ?l2
WHERE
{
  ?term1 skos:prefLabel ?l1.
  ?term2 skos:prefLabel ?l2.
  FILTER(!SAMETERM(?l1, ?l2)
         && contains(?l1,?l2) 
         && ( STRENDS(STRBEFORE(?l1, ?l2)," ") 
              || STRSTARTS(STRAFTER(?l1, ?l2), " ")
            ))
}
```

This requires that the string before/after the containing term must end/start with whitespace.  You may have to play around with this to get something that more closely models your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be by constructing a regex pattern on the fly, like:

```
FILTER(regex(concat("\\b", ?l1, "\\b"), ?l2))
```

I'm not entirely sure that SPARQL/XML Schema requires \b, but I think most implementations will have it.